# Effect of aria-hidden in Font Awesome

Tags: html, fonts, font-awesome

what's the effect of `aria-hidden` in Font Awesome?
Is it necessary to use it? why? or why not?

for example, I want to know the effect of `aria-hidden="true"` in the code below:

```
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: This link can help you <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, it makes the icon not visible to screen readers, to enhance accessibility.

From [the documentation](http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/):

> If you're using an icon to add some extra decoration or branding, it does not need to be announced to users as they are navigating your site or app aurally. Additionally, if you're using an icon to visually re-emphasize or add styling to content already present in your HTML, it does not need to be repeated to an assistive technology-using user. You can make sure this is not read by adding the aria-hidden="true" to your Font Awesome markup.

Answer (score -2):

> If you're using an icon to add some extra decoration or branding, it
>   does not need to be announced to users as they are navigating your
>   site or app aurally. Additionally, if you're using an icon to visually
>   re-emphasize or add styling to content already present in your HTML,
>   it does not need to be repeated to an assistive technology-using user.
>   You can make sure this is not read by adding the aria-hidden="true" to
>   your Font Awesome markup.

```
<i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

an icon being used as pure decoration

```
<h1 class="logo">
  <i class="fa fa-pied-piper" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  Pied Piper, A Middle-Out Compression Solution Making Data Storage Problems Smaller
</h1>
```

an icon being used as a logo

Source: http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/

Comment: I don't think the codes show what `aria-hidden:"true"` do to an element