# How to align icon next to text of link attribute with tailwind-css and css.gg

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is 100% a duplicated but I cannot get the icon left to the text of the `<a>`-attribute.

The closest I got is with this solution:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<link href='https://css.gg/mail.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<a href="mailto:mail@mail.mail"><i class="gg-mail float-left mr-1 top-1"></i>MAIL@MAIL.MAIL</a>
```

why does this solution not work in my project? Is it because of the css.gg?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27969559/3832357

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I solved it with flex! But any other solutions would be appreciated!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<link href='https://css.gg/mail.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<a class="flex items-center" href="mailto:mail@mail.mail"><i class="gg-mail mr-1"></i>MAIL@MAIL.MAIL</a>
```